# When performing unit testing using Spock, JpaRepository is not being injected and is returning as null

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spock, testcontainers

During my unit tests using Spock and Testcontainers, the JpaRepository is not functioning properly and is not being wired correctly. This issue persists even in non-integration tests.

As suggested in another discussion, I attempted to resolve the issue by adding the spock-spring dependency to my pom.xml file. It didn't work.

No matter the scenario, the repository consistently returns as null in all instances.

**An example:**

```
@Testcontainers
class PostgresTestContainer extends Specification {

    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository personRepository

    @Shared
    PostgreSQLContainer postgreSQLContainer = new PostgreSQLContainer("postgres:12-alpine")
            .withDatabaseName("test")
            .withUsername("test")
            .withPassword("test")

    def "waits until postgres accepts jdbc connections"() {

        when: "querying the database"
        def response = personRepository.findAll()

        then: "result is returned"
        response == 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The database is being initialized using `PostgresContainer` and `Testcontainers` annotation. However your test infrastructure doesn't know about the database. If using spring boot, then few things are missed

1. Add `SpringBootTest` or `DataJpaTest` annotation on top of the class. This way the spring application context is created with the right classes and `PersonRepository` will be injected
2. Switch to

```java
static postgresContainer = new PostgreSQLContainer("postgres:12-alpine")

@Shared
PostgreSQLContainer <?> postgres = postgresContainer
```

3. In order to make use of the database provided by Testcontainers, add

```java
@DynamicPropertySource
static void registerProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
    registry.add("spring.datasource.url", postgresContainer::getJdbcUrl);
    registry.add("spring.datasource.username", postgresContainer::getUsername);
    registry.add("spring.datasource.password", postgresContainer::getPassword);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to separate the container setup like the following:

`PostgresEnvrionement`

```
@Testcontainers
public class PostgresEnvironment {

    @Container
    public static PostgreSQLContainer postgreSQLContainer = PostgresTestContainer.getInstance();
}
```

`PostgresTestContainer`

```
public class PostgresTestContainer extends PostgreSQLContainer<PostgresTestContainer> {

    public static final String IMAGE_VERSION = "postgres:13.5";
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "test";
    private static PostgresTestContainer container;

    private PostgresTestContainer() {
        super(IMAGE_VERSION);
    }

    public static PostgresTestContainer getInstance() {
        if (container == null) {
            container = new PostgresTestContainer().withDatabaseName(DATABASE_NAME);
        }
        return container;
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        super.start();
        System.setProperty("DB_URL", container.getJdbcUrl());
        System.setProperty("DB_USERNAME", container.getUsername());
        System.setProperty("DB_PASSWORD", container.getPassword());
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
    }
}
```

In your test file extend the `PostgresEnvironment`

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest(classes = MainSpringBootApp.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class AssembleEventRepositoryIntegrationTest extends PostgresEnvrionement{

  // autowire jpa
  // write tests
}
```

in your `application-test.yml` file in the resources section under the test directory

```
spring:
  datasource:
    password: ${DB_USERNAME}
    username: ${DB_PASSWORD}
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    url: ${DB_URL}
```

Also make sure that your main `application.yml` file that is being used once launching your application (not in for running your tests) matches the same syntax as your test profile.